# Typescript module doesn't contain my source code

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a file named `Server.js` that contains `export class Program` and `<reference path='mscorlib.ts'/>`. When I build it with

```
tsc -t ES5 Server.ts --module commonjs --out Server.js
```

the generated file contains only the compiled source of `mscorlib.ts`, but no single sign of `Server.ts`. I've expected that there would have been an `module.exports = {Program: Program}` directive besides those sources, though. What could be a source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--out` flag only applies to input files that *aren't* external modules.

See also

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/289
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17
- [How to spread module across multiple AMD files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790262/how-to-spread-module-across-multiple-amd-files)
- [How do I split my module across multiple files in Typescript with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706455/how-do-i-split-my-module-across-multiple-files-in-typescript-with-node-js)

Comment: That moment when you understand that TS is not production ready and it's already in your code base.