# Generating a d.ts file with the compiler option generates a error for angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript

When using the tsc compiler option `"declaration": true` I get the following error:

`error TS4019: Implements clause of exported class 'MyClass' has or is using private name 'angular'.`

I do not get the error when using `"declaration": false`.

Using **TypeScript Version:**  2.0.3

Sample **Code**:

MyClass.ts

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts" />
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass implements angular.IServiceProvider {
        constructor() {
        }
        $get;
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "noEmitOnError": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "declaration": true
},
"exclude": [
  "node_modules"
]
}
```

There is a github repo on https://github.com/iwhp/issues/tree/master/typescript-bug-declaration-file-with-angular

**Expected behavior:**

A .d.ts file should be created.

**Addition to the sample above**

I added the following class, to show that MyClass.ts is used here.

MyClass2.ts

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts" />
module MyModule {
    export class MyClassB implements angular.IServiceProvider {
        constructor(myClass: MyModule.MyClass) {
        }
        $get;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are always going to compile it with typescript 2.0, you can replace this line

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts" />
```

with more modern

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

Then .d.ts file is created, but it's empty because you did not export MyModule - you need an `export` for it too:

```
export module MyModule {
```

UPDATE

Now, if you want to split module `MyModule` into several files, I could not find any way to reference angular type definitions while keeping module `MyModule` internal. This error message about `angular` being private looks like a bug - in `angular.d.ts` identifier `angular` is declared several times, and some of these declarations are with `export` so I have no idea why it's considered private.

If you want to go the route of making your modules external, then you can use workaround described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37480976/43848) - you need to have MyClass and MyClassB at top level in their source files, and to have separate MyModule file that re-exports them both.

The drawbacks are:

- you can't compile to single file without changing module type to `amd` or `system`, so you have to add `"module": "amd", "moduleResolution": "node"` to `tsconfig.json` for this to compile (compiling to separate files is unaffected)
- MyClass and MyClassB are still being exported at top level, as well as in the `MyModule` module (you could move them to subdirectory if you want)
- there is circular reference between MyClassB and MyModule (not really a drawback, node module resolution should handle it just fine, but it looks very odd).

The complete files:

**MyClass.ts**

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

export class MyClass implements angular.IServiceProvider {
    constructor() {
    }

    $get;
}
```

**MyClassB.ts**

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import * as MyModule from './MyModule';

export class MyClassB implements angular.IServiceProvider {
    constructor(myClass: MyModule.MyClass) {
    }

    $get;
}
```

**MyModule.ts**

```
export {MyClass} from './MyClass';
export {MyClassB} from './MyClassB';
```

Comment: Thankx artem. This does work, but I have now added a new class called MyClassB which uses MyClass. Now I get the following messages when using your proposal: error TS2305: Module 'MyModule' has no exported member 'MyClass'.